GoDaddy, VPS, cPanel: Experiencing issues in listening api calls with https after installing SSL for my domain
Before installing SSL for my domain (i.e. apiagoverse.com) on GoDaddy VPS cPanel, the following CURL commands were logging the expected output to the terminal:

curl http://ipaddress:8000/api/v1/status // Welcome to the Commercial Website Backend


curl http://apiagoverse.com:8000/api/v1/status // Welcome to the Commercial Website Backend

Here, 'ipaddress' is the placeholder for my IP address.
After successfully installing SSL for my domain on the GoDaddy VPS cPanel account and configuring my node app (index.js) accordingly with HTTPS, the following started happening,

The API calls for the URLs with the IP address were no longer being listened to, which was obvious as SSL only allowed for API calls with the domain name in the URL. (I guessed that)
The responses for the API calls with the domain name with https and http were not giving any expected output, as follows

curl http://apiagoverse.com/api/v1/status
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://apiagoverse.com/api/v1/status">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>

curl http://apiagoverse.com/api/v1/status
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://apiagoverse.com/api/v1/status">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
[apiagoverse@85 ~]$ ^C
[apiagoverse@85 ~]$ curl https://apiagoverse.com/api/v1/status
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>

The node app (rootDir/index.js):
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import https from 'https';
import fs from 'fs';
import { config } from "dotenv";

// Import Routes
import Routes from "./routes/index.js";

// Configuration
config();
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 443;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "50mb" }));
app.use(cors());

// Routes
app.use(Routes);

// Handle 404
app.use((req, res) => {
  res
    .status(404)
    .json({ success: false, message: "Requested resource not found" });
});

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('../ssl/keys/privateKey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('../ssl/crts/certificate.crt'),
};

// Start Server
https.createServer(options, app).listen(port);
enter code here

The main routes file (rootDir/routes/index.js):
import { Router } from "express";
const router = Router();

router.get("/api/v1/status", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json("Welcome to the Commercial Website Backend");
});

// rest of the routes

export default router;

I also tried my luck with .htaccess configuration as GoDaddy told me they are not good with Nginx and I was not provided the direct access to Apache. The following is my .htacess file:
# Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Rewrite rules to direct traffic to the Node.js backend
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.agoverse\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/v1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8000/$1 [P,L]

# Handle React app requests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.agoverse\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^agoverse\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]

But this also didn't work.
Can anyone put some light on my problem and find me a way to resolution :D.
